# how data stores in dynamodb in express node.js and angular 7 application?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, amazon-dynamodb, mean-stack

I am creating a simple application, Angular 7 form having some inputs connect with node.js and then store data in the database (Dynamodb),
DATA like name father name mob number. I did for MongoDB in which I create a model and link them but dynamodb is different

how I define model? 
how do they connect with angular?

I have 2 folders one angular and one API folder for node express now what should I download local files of dynamodb, now next step i dont know what should i do

kindly help